# (Angular) TypeError: Cannot read property 'StartDate' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I've spent almost 3 weeks with Angular 5 and fairly new to web development. I'm trying to send a '*Date*' type datatype from the component.html to the component.ts which further sends it to a service.

However, I don't know why I get the above [**error** (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e360x.jpg) cause I did exactly the same thing in another component and it still works fine. It's probably a rookie mistake, but after countless searching, most of the solutions either didn't fit my problem or they were way beyond my level of understanding.

> rooms.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DatepickerOptions } from 'ng2-datepicker';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Room } from './room.model';
import { RoomsService } from './rooms.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-rooms',
  templateUrl: './rooms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rooms.component.css'],
  providers:[RoomsService]
})

export class RoomsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private roomService: RoomsService) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {  
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm)
  {
    console.log(form.value);
  }    
}
```

> rooms.component.html

```
<form #roomForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(roomForm)">    
  <div  class="form-row">    
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" name="StartDate" #StartDate="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="roomService.userSelection.StartDate" placeholder="Start Date" required> 
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="EndDate" #EndDate="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="roomService.userSelection.EndDate" placeholder="End Date" required> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">    
      <div class="form-group col-md-8">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Submit</button> 
      </div>     
  </div>   
</form>
```

> rooms.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Room } from './room.model';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';



@Injectable()
export class RoomsService {

  userSelection:Room;
  roomList: Room[];      

  constructor(private http: Http) {       
   }

  getRoomList(StartDate, EndDate){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:17518/api/RoomPriceAndStatus')
    .map((data: Response)=>{
      return data.json() as Room[];
    }).toPromise().then(x =>{
      this.roomList = x;
    })
  }
}
```

> room.model.ts

```
export class Room{
    Id: number;
    StartDate: Date;
    EndDate: Date;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `userSelection` member of your `RoomsService` is undefined. You might want to initialize it to a default instance of `Room`.

Comment: @Vaibhav In that case, feel free to upvote the answer. Also, you should mark one of the answers as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot itself explains where your code is failing.

Inside your `rooms.component.html` template, you are binding `[(ngModel)]="roomService.userSelection.StartDate"`.

Check and make sure `userSelection` object gets proper value. Ultimately `StartDate` sits there. `userSelection` must be `undefined` that's why you are getting this error.

Try putting a condition `*ngIf`, you could able to see it.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6" *ngIf="roomService.userSelection">
```

This will display your section only if `roomService.userSelection` object has some value/ is not `undefined`.